# Dynamic Http Streaming in Android to play live Flash video

Tags: android, flash

I am trying to connect my android application with FTP Server which is broadcasting multiple streams using Dynamic Http Streaming at different bit rates.Flash Messaging Server(FMS) is using H.264 codec to broadcast video in flv format.On client side(Android) I am getting f4m(manifest (xml) file)) having diffrent streams.
I am unable to use the f4m file to fetch video in android from FMS.

```
String url = "http://d2233avv69kunu.cloudfront.net/hds-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent/livestream.f4m"; 
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
   // videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.setVideoPath(str);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

    //VMRuntime.getRuntime().setMinimumHeapSize(40);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);  

    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    System.out.println("Max Memory - "+java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()); 
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
     {
           public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
           {                 
                 videoView.start();
           }
     });
```

In above code I am trying to run video in Video View component by passing link of f4m file. 
Flash encoder convert video into 3 file formats as listed below

1. .f4m (manifest files) - Bootstrap Info,Metadata, Bitrate, Flash Access license Server location
2. .f4f (fragment files) - extends the F4V format,MP4 fragment std
3. .f4x (index files) - binary

Kindly provide solution to play video on different android devices via Http Streaming in android.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1) You have left something out of your code. What is `str` that you are passing to `setVideoPath`? (this is somewhat irrelevant, though...)

2) The `MediaPlayer` (and thereby `VideoView`) cannot play Flash video at all. It's simply [not supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). It definitely won't understand an XML file, either, so passing it the f4m file is pointless.

Comment: I do want to play live flash video in android via Dynamic Http Streaming. Sry 4 irrelevant code just ignore it ........ Plz provide me guidelines to achieve the task.

Comment: You can install the Flash plugin for Android and embed a `WebView` in your application. [See here](http://synesthesia.it/playing-flash-flv-videos-in-android-applications).

Comment: Since adobe has removed flash support from android ICS,Jelly Bean & Kitkat.Therefore i am unable to download flash from adobe for my android.Although my task is to achieve dynamic Http Streaming in android.

Comment: HTTP streaming works. It's the Flash format that doesn't. Serve the video in a different format (like MPEG TS) and you shouldn't have any problems.